# Is setting "ASP.NET Impersonation" possible using WiX 3.x with IISExtension?

Tags: wix

I have this component in my .wxs file:

```
  <Component Id="Component.IisConfiguration" Guid="[COMPONENT_GUID_IISSITE]">
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="IIS.AppPool" Name="[WEB_APP_POOL_NAME]" Identity="networkService" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
    <iis:WebSite Id="IIS.WebSite" Description="[WEB_APP_NAME]" SiteId="[WEB_APP_SITEID]" Directory="TARGETDIR" >          
      <iis:WebApplication Id="IIS.WebSite.Application" Name="[WEB_APP_POOL_NAME]" WebAppPool="IIS.AppPool" />
      <iis:WebAddress Id="IIS.WebSite.WebAddress.Port" Port="[WEB_APP_ADDRESS_PORT]" />
      <iis:WebDirProperties Id="IIS.WebSite.Authentication" WindowsAuthentication="yes"  />
    </iis:WebSite>
  </Component>
```

Is it possible to set "ASP.NET Impersonation" anywhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's no out-of-the-box switch for this. You can have a custom action which calls:

```
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT/section:identity /impersonate:true
```

See [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708.aspx) for more information.

On the other hand, you can always set this setting [on the application level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755253.aspx), and use the standard `XmlConfig` element to modify the web.config file for this.

Comment: Or you could add the feature to the existing custom action. We can help on wix-devs@lists.sourceforge.net.

Comment: I had the developer add an identity@impersonate tag to their web.config and I didn't have to do anything in the installer.