# Impersonating different users during install in WiX setup

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, wix, impersonation

I've just created a WiX v3.5 installer to install my Web application to IIS7. I have custom actions to allow the user to choose which website and app pool they want and to name the Virtual directory via the dialogs.

But now I've come to authentication and I'm stumped. I am trying to enable impersonation and allow the user to enter their impersonation login and password. I had this working fine in my Visual Studion 2010 setup projects so now I need to replicate the same in WiX.

Aparently this can be done via an appcmd as per this question: [Is setting "ASP.NET Impersonation" possible using WiX 3.x with IISExtension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252934/is-setting-asp-net-impersonation-possible-using-wix-3-x-with-iisextension) but I can't seem to get this working. Can i add this in my product.wxs and wrap it in a custom action? Any ideas anyone? Any help would be appreciated?

```
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT/section:identity /impersonate:true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I managed to get this working myself , so if anyone else is having the same issue , i fixed this by modifying my web.config during my install:

To do this i added the following code to my product.wsx to edit my web.config , using properties which i assigned to text boxes in a new dialog to allow the user to enter the impersonation username and password on install :

```
<Component Id="Web.config" Guid="2ED81B77-F153-4003-9006-4770D789D4B6">
        <File Id="Web.config" Name="Web.config" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)MyWebApp\Web.config" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" />
        <util:XmlFile Id="system.webidentity" File="[INSTALLLOCATION]Web.config" Action="createElement" ElementPath="/configuration/system.web" Name="identity" Sequence="1" />
        <util:XmlFile Id="system.webIdentityAttribute" Action="setValue" File="[INSTALLLOCATION]Web.config" ElementPath="/configuration/system.web/identity" Name="impersonate" Value="true" Sequence="2" />
        <util:XmlFile Id="system.webIdentityAttribute2" Action="setValue" File="[INSTALLLOCATION]Web.config" ElementPath="/configuration/system.web/identity" Name="password" Value="[IMPERSONATIONUSERPASSWORD]" Sequence="3" />
        <util:XmlFile Id="system.webIdentityAttribute3" Action="setValue" File="[INSTALLLOCATION]Web.config" ElementPath="/configuration/system.web/identity" Name="userName" Value="[IMPERSONATIONUSER]" Sequence="4" />
```

Note if you are adding your files automatically to your Wix project using msbuild and heat , you'll have to ensure you arent copying your web.config here , or if you are , remove my web.config your Target settings. Otherwise you'll get duplication errors .

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<MSBuild Projects="%(ProjectReference.FullPath)" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=AnyCPU" Condition="'%(ProjectReference.PackageThisProject)'=='True'" />
<Delete Files="%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\web.config">
</Delete>
<PropertyGroup>
  <LinkerBaseInputPaths>%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\</LinkerBaseInputPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
<HeatDirectory OutputFile="%(ProjectReference.Filename).wxs" Directory="%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\" DirectoryRefId="INSTALLLOCATION" ComponentGroupName="%(ProjectReference.Filename)_Project" SuppressCom="true" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRegistry="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" AutoGenerateGuids="false" GenerateGuidsNow="true" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" Condition="'%(ProjectReference.PackageThisProject)'=='True'" />   </Target>
```